# BufExplorer: Set "Don't locate buffer" as default

Tags: plugin-bufexplorer

In the BufExplorer plug-in, is there any way to set "Don't locate buffer" as the default at startup?

Comment: What does the documentation of the plugin say about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the `a` command to toggle whether you are taken to the active window when selecting a buffer, see [the docs at `:help bufexplorer`](https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer/blob/master/doc/bufexplorer.txt):

> ```
>                                                      *g:bufExplorerFindActive*
> To control whether you are taken to the active window when selecting a buffer,
> use: >
>  let g:bufExplorerFindActive=0        " Do not go to active window.
>  let g:bufExplorerFindActive=1        " Go to active window.
> The default is to be taken to the active window.
> ```

You can place the command in your vimrc, for example.

Comment: Thanks, D. Ben Knoble. I don't have that documentation in my Cygwin installation of vim. I was able to find it online. It was educational to find that Vim plug-ins have a standard convention for their documentation files. Until then, I thought the documentation consisted of the F1 help for BufExplorer. Subsquently, I thought that I might not have installed a documentation package. Bafflingly, however my search of the Cygwin packages for `bufexplorer` yields nothing.

Comment: @user2153235 when you install a plugin, you should run `:helptags ALL` to generate doc tags. Then it will appear in `:help local-additions` and you can use `:help <the-plugin>` (typically)

Comment: I suspect that I need the *<name-of-plugin>.txt* file first. Currently going through [this](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#05.5) help snippet to install `bufexplorer.txt`.  Also trying to locate the `bufexplorer.txt` file for version 7.4.23 instead of the current version 7.4.26.  Because I don't like surprises and I also hack the source file for customizations.

Comment: @user2153235 oh, hm. How do you typically install Vim plugins? The ways most people do grab all the files, including the ones in doc

Comment: Apart from whatever may come with the Cygwin installation, I don't recall plugins being a major part of my use of Vim over the decades. The current `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin` contains only BufExplorer and a small custom *.vim file from UseNet long ago. I found 7.4.23 at [GitHub](https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer) by clicking `releases`, finding the version, then clicking `Assests`. GitHub also links to [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42) where "versions" are tabulated.

Comment: The GitHub may be more reliable than vim.org for older version plugins.  The latter yields "Vim Online Error\\Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" when clicking on an older version.

Comment: Since `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles` is system folder, I used an administrator account to create folder `doc` therein as a peer to the folder `plugin`.  I placed `bufexplorer.txt` in the latter, ran Vim from the `doc` directory, then issued `:helptags .`  All users had to be given read permission to the entire `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/doc` subtree.  In Cygwin, all users also needed "execute" permission to the `doc` folder, which allows them to descend into it.

Comment: You can install plugins in your home directory (help runtimepath)

Comment: Thanks. I want the same ease of access to plug-ins and documentation both when doing administrative housekeeping and when using my workhorse user account.  So for Vim, I install everything in site/system directories.